# Phonegap downloaded image on sdcard

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

I want to store an image on sdcard (android) with phonegap. But it is not working. I download the image with filetransfer.download. But it jumps in the error callback. The errocode that I get is 1. Here my Code:

```
window.resolveLocalFileSystemURI(cordova.file.externalRootDirectory  + "/Pictures", function (fileSystem) {

        var fileTransfer = new FileTransfer();
        var uri = encodeURI("MyTopsecretPHPFunctionThatReturnsAnImage...");
        var path = fileSystem.toURL() + "example.jpg";

        alert(path);

        fileTransfer.download(
            uri,
            path,

        function(entry) {
            alert("success!!" + path);
            refreshMedia.refresh(path); // Refresh the image gallery
        },

        function(error) {
            alert(error.source);
            alert(error.target);
            alert(error.code);
        },
        false, 
            { headers: { "Authorization": "dGVzdHVzZXJuYW1lOnRlc3RwYXNzd29yZA==" }
        });
    },function(error) {
        alert(error);
});
```

When I put it in cordova.file.externalDataDirectory it is working. Why can't I access to the pictures folder, or any other folder at the sdcard root directory?

And another question: where can I store the image on IOS? I want to show it on gallery...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution: I just added the Line:

```
fileSystem.getDirectory("Pictures", {create: true, exclusive: false});
```

Now I'm able to get the access rights on the sdcard.